# Migrate from WordPerfect to OpenOffice

Tags: word-processor, open-office

My WordPerfect program is no longer working; hence, I will start using OpenOffice...HOWEVER...

I have tons of WP (word perfect) documents stored and OpenOffice does not support WP files. ALSO, the "import" option gives me an imperfect document.

What free software can I use?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but LibreOffice Writer lists WordPerfect Document (*.wpd) in the open dialog box. How well it translates documents I can't say.

Comment: I am asking this question because **I already tried it** and it just gave me jebrish jargon And NO! It does NOT include/have a `WordPerfect Document (*.wpd)` option

Comment: You wrote Open Office not LibreOffice. Also what LO version and OS? I see the option on Windows 7 and LibreOffice 5.3.0.3.